# How procurement product not create purchase order new

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

When creating automatic purchase orders, do not group the items on existing orders as `Odoo` does, but you have to split them.

When automatically creating purchase orders (on-order procurement), do not group items on existing draft purchase order for the project, systematically create a new purchase order.

I want to override function for create purchase order new to supply an article not create in existing purchase orders.

```
    def _make_po_get_domain(self, partner):
    gpo = self.rule_id.group_propagation_option
    group = (gpo == 'fixed' and self.rule_id.group_id) or \
            (gpo == 'propagate' and self.group_id) or False

    domain = (
        ('partner_id', '=', partner.id),
        ('state', '=', 'draft'),
        ('picking_type_id', '=', self.rule_id.picking_type_id.id),
        ('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id),
        ('dest_address_id', '=', self.partner_dest_id.id))
    if group:
        domain += (('group_id', '=', group.id),)
    return domain

@api.multi
def make_po(self):
    cache = {}
    res = []
    for procurement in self:
        suppliers = procurement.product_id.seller_ids\
            .filtered(lambda r: (not r.company_id or r.company_id == procurement.company_id) and (not r.product_id or r.product_id == procurement.product_id))
        if not suppliers:
            procurement.message_post(body=_('No vendor associated to product %s. Please set one to fix this procurement.') % (procurement.product_id.name))
            continue
        supplier = procurement._make_po_select_supplier(suppliers)
        partner = supplier.name

        domain = procurement._make_po_get_domain(partner)

        if domain in cache:
            po = cache[domain]
        else:
            po = self.env['purchase.order'].search([dom for dom in domain])
            po = po[0] if po else False
            cache[domain] = po
        if not po:
            vals = procurement._prepare_purchase_order(partner)
            po = self.env['purchase.order'].create(vals)
            name = (procurement.group_id and (procurement.group_id.name + ":") or "") + (procurement.name != "/" and procurement.name or procurement.move_dest_id.raw_material_production_id and procurement.move_dest_id.raw_material_production_id.name or "")
            message = _("This purchase order has been created from: <a href=# data-oe-model=procurement.order data-oe-id=%d>%s</a>") % (procurement.id, name)
            po.message_post(body=message)
            cache[domain] = po
        elif not po.origin or procurement.origin not in po.origin.split(', '):
            # Keep track of all procurements
            if po.origin:
                if procurement.origin:
                    po.write({'origin': po.origin + ', ' + procurement.origin})
                else:
                    po.write({'origin': po.origin})
            else:
                po.write({'origin': procurement.origin})
            name = (self.group_id and (self.group_id.name + ":") or "") + (self.name != "/" and self.name or self.move_dest_id.raw_material_production_id and self.move_dest_id.raw_material_production_id.name or "")
            message = _("This purchase order has been modified from: <a href=# data-oe-model=procurement.order data-oe-id=%d>%s</a>") % (procurement.id, name)
            po.message_post(body=message)
        if po:
            res += [procurement.id]

        # Create Line
        po_line = False
        for line in po.order_line:
            if line.product_id == procurement.product_id and line.product_uom == procurement.product_id.uom_po_id:
                procurement_uom_po_qty = procurement.product_uom._compute_quantity(procurement.product_qty, procurement.product_id.uom_po_id)
                seller = procurement.product_id._select_seller(
                    partner_id=partner,
                    quantity=line.product_qty + procurement_uom_po_qty,
                    date=po.date_order and po.date_order[:10],
                    uom_id=procurement.product_id.uom_po_id)

                price_unit = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price_company(seller.price, line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id, line.taxes_id, self.company_id) if seller else 0.0
                if price_unit and seller and po.currency_id and seller.currency_id != po.currency_id:
                    price_unit = seller.currency_id.compute(price_unit, po.currency_id)

                po_line = line.write({
                    'product_qty': line.product_qty + procurement_uom_po_qty,
                    'price_unit': price_unit,
                    'procurement_ids': [(4, procurement.id)]
                })
                break
        if not po_line:
            vals = procurement._prepare_purchase_order_line(po, supplier)
            self.env['purchase.order.line'].create(vals)
    return res
```